# EKEvent color icon

Tags: ios, colors, icons, ekevent

In my app, I create EKEvents, and put them in a an EKCalendar.
In order to make some events stand out in the Calendar, I prefix the event.title with a bullet.

I noticed however, that all entries in Apple's Birthday Calendar have a red Birthday Present icon as a prefix.

For my purposes, I can, rather than a bullet use (a limited number-why?) of Unicode characters, as a prefix, but, just like the Birthday Present icon, I would like to also give it a color.

Since event.title is just an NSString, I assume Apple is using a private API to colorize that Present Icon, but against all odds, I was wondering if any of you knows a trick to establish a color icon in a regular way.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: did you tried this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325352/ekcalendarekcalendar-cgcolor-is-not-setting-color-in-iphones-calendar

Comment: I don't want to set the color of a Calendar, but I want to set the color of a character/symbol of an Event.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can read the calendar.cgColor.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekcalendar/1615894-cgcolor